# Validación de campos en un formulario - PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, formularios, validación

Tengo este código php para validar un formulario html. El caso es que no se como hacer que para el campo 'paginas' que es un `<input type="text" name="paginas" value="" maxlength="3">` sólo se admitan números.

Había buscado como hacerlo y encontré `is_numeric` y lo aplique de esta forma `is_numeric(isset($_POST['paginas']))===false` pero no me funciona correctamente.

Si alguno de vosotros sabe como funciona el is_numeric o sabe alguna otra forma de hacerlo lo agradecería. 
'Muchas gracias y un saludo!

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if (isset($_POST['autor'])==null || isset($_POST['titulo'])==null ||
      isset($_POST['paginas'])==null || is_numeric(isset($_POST['paginas']))===false || isset($_POST['sinopsis'])==null ) {

    echo "ERROR! Todos los campos han de estar rellenados.";
    exit;
  }else {
    echo "<strong>Autor:  </strong>"; echo $_POST['autor']; echo "<br/>";
    echo "<strong>Titulo:  </strong>"; echo $_POST['titulo']; echo "<br/>";
    echo "<strong>Paginas:  </strong>"; echo $_POST['paginas']; echo "<br/><br/>";
    echo "<strong>Sinopsis:  </strong>";echo $_POST['sinopsis'];echo "<br/>";

}
}
```

Comment: la validación tiene que ser en php ? por que en el html puedes cambiar el input de tipo text a number y ya está

Comment: @CamiloVasquez de esa forma sólo dejaría poner tipos de datos int?

Comment: Claro, si le dices al input que es de tipo number solo te deja ingresar números

Comment: @CamiloVasquez probado y funcionando correctamente, muchas gracias! No había caído en ese detalle.

Comment: Genial, te lo publicaré como respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma fácil y sencilla de lograr lo que quieres es utilizar las mismas herramientas que nos ofrece HTML, cambiando el `input` de tipo `text` a tipo `number`

```html
<input type="number" name="paginas" value="">
```

`

Comment: La validación en cliente es la manera de validar **visualmente** de manera rápida pero no efectiva, con simplemente acceder a la consola y modificar el tipo de campo, si no lo validas en servidor tu aplicación estará rota y/o vulnerable.

Answer (score 3):

Aun que puedes utilizar el `type="number"` en el input de tu formulario esto no garantiza que solo se puedan enviar números, la recomendación es que igualmente valides siempre los datos de lado servidor.

Pongamos tu código un poco más legible:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if ( isset($_POST['autor']) 
         AND isset($_POST['titulo']) 
         AND isset($_POST['paginas'])
         AND is_numeric($_POST['paginas'])
         AND isset($_POST['sinopsis']) 
        ) 
    {
        echo "<strong>Autor:  </strong>".$_POST['autor']."<br/>";
        echo "<strong>Título:  </strong>".$_POST['titulo']."<br/>";
        echo "<strong>Páginas:  </strong>".$_POST['paginas']."<br/><br/>";
        echo "<strong>Sinopsis:  </strong>".$_POST['sinopsis']."<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR! Todos los campos han de estar rellenados.";
        exit;
    }
}
```

No tiene sentido igualar a `null`, tanto `isset()` como `is_numeric()` devuelven true o false nunca van a devolver `null`, tampoco tiene sentido anidar `isset()` dentro  de `is_numeric()` ya que esto retornara siempre FALSE ya que `isset()` devuelve un boleano.